# Cannot read and write to the same file in an exported Processing app

Tags: processing, datastore

I am using an external `.txt` file to save the incrementing name index for whenever someone "takes a picture" in my app (i.e. `image_1.jpg`, `image_2.jpg`, etc...). I am trying to save the data externally so that a user does not overwrite their pictures each time they run the program. However, because of the way that Processing packages its contents for export I cannot both read and write to the same file. It reads the appropriate file located in the apps package contents, however, when it tries to write to that file, it creates a new folder in the same directory as the app itself and writes to a new file with the same name instead.

Essentially, it reads the proper file but refuses to write to it, instead making a copy and writing to that one. The app runs fine but every time you open it and take pictures you overwrite the images you already had.

I have tried naming the "write to" location the explicitly same link as where the exported app stores the data folder inside the package contents (`Contents/Resources/Java/data/assets`) but this creates a copy of this directory in the same file as the app.

I have also tried excluding the file I am trying to read/write from my data folder when I export the app by changing the read code to `../storage/pictureNumber.txt` and then putting this file next to app itself. When I do this the app doesn't launch at all because it is looking in its own data folder for storage and refuses to go outside of itself with `../` . Has anyone had luck both reading from and writing to the same file in an exported processing .app?

Here is the code for the class that is handling the loading and saving of the file:

```
class Camera {
    PImage cameraImage;
    int cameraPadding = 10;
    int cameraWidth = 60;
    int opacity = 0;
    int flashDecrementer = 50; //higher number means quicker flash
    int pictureName;

    Camera() {
        String[] pictureIndex = loadStrings("assets/pictureNumber.txt");
        pictureName = int(pictureIndex[0]);
        cameraImage = loadImage("assets/camera.jpg");
        String _pictureName = "" + char(pictureName); 
        println(pictureName); 
    }

    void display(float mx, float my) {
        image(cameraImage, cameraPadding, cameraPadding,
              cameraWidth, cameraWidth-cameraWidth/5);
    }

    boolean isOver(float mx, float my) {
        if (mx >= cameraPadding &&
            mx <= cameraPadding+cameraWidth &&
            my >= cameraPadding &&
            my <= cameraPadding+cameraWidth-cameraWidth/5) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    void captureImage() {
        save("pictures/"+lines.picturePrefix+"_"+pictureName+".jpg");
        pictureName++;
        String _null = "";
        // String _tempPictureName = _null.valueOf(pictureName);
        String[] _pictureName = {_null.valueOf(pictureName)}; 
        saveStrings("assets/pictureNumber.txt", _pictureName);
        println(_pictureName);
    }

    void flash() {
        fill(255, opacity);
        rect(0,0,width,height);
        opacity -= flashDecrementer;
        if(opacity <= 0) opacity = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. When I replicate the part of your code that loads and saves I get a null the first time the app runs, it then writes to the file in the assets folder and subsequent executions run ok.

Comment: Did you export the app or run it in processing? It works fine in processing, but not once the app has been exported. It actually doesn't fail to run ever, it just overwrites previous images because `pictureNumber` resets to 1 each time the exported app is run.

Comment: I tried it as an app. Here's the code I tested with (maybe I misunderstood something): http://pastebin.com/sY1rCLHV

Comment: By the way, you don't need to instantiate a String object to call valueOf() : _null.valueOf(pictureName). You can call it as String.valueOf(pictureName) - it's a static method.

Comment: Hm, that actually seemed to work pretty well! Do you have any idea why my code isn't behaving the same? Also, why does the app run during its first time being opened (before f.txt) is created? When I have been trying to trouble shoot this problem, and run my app without the text file I am trying to read from I get a fatal NullPointerException and the app doesnt run at all. I have had to use try and catch. Would it help if I sent you a copy of the project I am working on? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I just tried applying your little sketch to an example of my needs and the few modifications I made to make it apply to my numbering sceme broke your working example. Here is the code http://pastebin.com/mfxY1gGv.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching I found that you have to use savePath() in order to read from a directory outside of the project.jar. The camera class constructor now looks like this:

```
path = savePath("storage");
println(path);
String[] pictureIndex = loadStrings(path+"/pictureNumber.txt");
pictureName = int(pictureIndex[0]);
cameraImage = loadImage("assets/camera.jpg");
String _pictureName = ""+char(pictureName);
```

and everything works!